# Trigonometric functions $\in$.

Tags: trigonometry, notation

I am new to Trig functions and have encounter this symbol $\in$ (element of) when asked to sketch a graph. For example here is my Trig Function $f(t) = 2 + 3\sin(t - pi/2)$.

I am then asked to sketch the function for $t\in [-6,6]$ I am wondering if this simply means the sketch must go from $-6$ to $6$ on the x-axis of the sketch.

Comment: Yes, that is what it means.

Comment: Yes, inclusive of $-6$ and $6$. By the way, $\in$ is not a trigonometric function, it's just a symbol.

Comment: Alright thank you. Sorry for any bad terminology.

Comment: $t\in[-6,6]$ means exactly the same as $-6\le t\le-6$. By the way, in this case I'd call the horizontal axis the $t$ axis rather than the $x$ axis.